# How to group by date, month and week date in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by

I have a column createdAt which is datetype timestamp , I want to count how many records I have in that period. I try to group them by "DATE"
However, I get an error:
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Here is my query:

```
select "createdAt" as period, count(id) as count from members where ("createdAt" between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-10') group by date("createdAt");
```

How do I create these tables in SQL?

```
__________________
count | period
__________________
11    | 2022-08-08
```

```
__________________
count | period
__________________
11    | Monday
```

Comment: I have a column createdAt which is datetype Now(), - there is no such datatype in mysql do you mean datetime? if so group_by date(your column)

Comment: @P.Salmon yes. I updated my question. Is the date generated with NOW() a datetime?

Comment: `now()` isn't a data type, it's a function that returns a value of type `timestamp with time zone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resolved with `extract`.
Here is the code:

```
select extract(week from "createdAt") as period, count(id) as n_people from members where '20220801' <= "createdAt" and "createdAt" <= '20220810' group by extract(week from "createdAt");
```

Comment: Extract Week works well, most of the time. However it can give unexpected results. 1. The last few days of Dec may be in the first week of the following year. 2. The first few days in Jan may be in the last week of the previous year. Make sure you are OK with these. Try: `with test( "createdAt") as (values (date '2025-12-31'), (date '2023-01-01')) select "createdAt" , extract ('isoyear' from "createdAt") "ISO year" , extract( 'week' from "createdAt") "ISO week" from test;` to see this and that you are comfortable with the results.

Answer (score 0):

The DATEFIRST setting depends on SQL Server's language version. The default value for U.S. English is 7 **(i.e. Sunday)**.

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(week, RegistrationDate) AS Week,
  COUNT(CustomerID) AS Registrations
FROM Customers
WHERE '20180101' <= RegistrationDate
  AND RegistrationDate < '20190101'
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, RegistrationDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(week, RegistrationDate);
```

Comment: I get the same error :> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Also I don't have a week column. I put there createdAt, but if I leave there week I get this error:  column "week" does not exist

Comment: You need date_part, not datepart. And "week" must be placed between single quotes 'week'. Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html